# Getting stuck on Core Service call

Tags: core-service, 2013-sp1

I am making a GUI Extensions that needs to get all Components and their schemas that are being used on the pages that the user selects.

To do this, I just get all PageData's (CoreServce) for the pages the User selected in the list. Then for each PageData I get the ComponentData and its SchemaFieldsData.

Now after exactly 164 calls on one of our environments and 27 on a local vagrant box, the process gets stuck on the call I make to the core service. It will stay stuck until the 10 min timeout has passed, and will then continue doing it's thing. The operation that hung the process also seems to be successful as the data is printed out in my logging (data only the componentData has).

When I debugged the TcmServiceHost it is stuck on a TryRead action to our MySQL database. But as this is a Read action, this makes it only stranger to me ..

Does anybody have any ideas as to what could cause this?

As for now, it is working, but the 10 min delay now and then slows the pages/min rate down drastically.

Thanks!

Thomas

---

Edit - Rick Pannekoek's question

Example of how I call the core service:

```
private static ComponentData GetComponent(string id, string requestingUser)
{
    ComponentData componentData;
    using (var client = TridionCoreServiceFactory.GetSessionAwareCoreServiceClient(requestingUser))
    {
        componentData = client.Read(id, DefaultReadOptions) as ComponentData;
    }
    return componentData;
}
```

The TridionCoreServiceFactory.GetSessionAwareCoreServiceClient function

```
public static IDisposableSessionAwareCoreServiceClient GetSessionAwareCoreServiceClient(string user = null)
{
    var client = new DisposableSessionAwareCoreServiceClient(EndPoint);
    if (user != null)
    {
        client.Impersonate(user);
        Log.Debug("Impersonated Core Service session as {0}", user);
    }
    return client;
}
```

The implementation of the DisposableSessionAwareCoreServiceClient class:

```
public class DisposableSessionAwareCoreServiceClient : SessionAwareCoreServiceClient, IDisposableSessionAwareCoreServiceClient 
{
...
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_isDisposed || !disposing)
            return;
        _isDisposed = true;
        try
        {
            if (State != CommunicationState.Closed)
                base.Close();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException)
        {
            Abort();
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            Abort();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Abort();
        }
    }
....
}
```

The IDisposableSessionAwareCoreServiceClient interface extends ISessionAwareCoreService and IDisposable

Comment: Are you properly closing/disposing your CoreServiceClient objects?

Comment: I created an extensions on the SessionAwareCoreServiceClient of Tridion which also implements IDisposable. When an instance is disposed, it automaticly closes the connection + I only call the client within a 'using' statement. (code added in my question for clarity).

Comment: Ok, that looks fine. Can you elaborate what you mean with "a TryRead action on our MySQL database" (CM doesn't support MySQL). Did you analyze a Core Service WCF trace?

Comment: My bad it was MS SQL. But as i put in my answer below, I found the problem.

Comment: I'd consider upgrading it to use the Alchemy framework when possible.  There is a way within Alchemy to call the Core Service directly, and lots of helpers and other goodness.  It also makes installing GUI extensions a pleasure.  https://github.com/Alchemy4Tridion/Alchemy4Tridion

Comment: We considered using Alchemy but not all of our customers would allow it, as it is now in Beta. Besides that, our CoreServiceClient implementation closely follows that of Alchemy. 

But in the long term.. yeah we are also moving to Alchemy. I'm looking forward to releasing my first, own, Alchemy extension. But is still WIP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue:
There was one call to the core service in my code which was not encapsulated with a 'using' statement.